# Externalizing logging in Spring Boot apps

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to externalize logging configuration. However, any configuration I establish (e.g. `-Dlogback.configurationFile=...`) is wiped out the moment I call `SpringApplication.run()`. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'logging.config' (or use one of the the conventional locations, e.g. 'classpath:/logback.xml'). Docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration.